# Spring Cloud Config Server not registering as client to Spring Boot Admin

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I have Spring Cloud config server and trying to register it to Spring Boot admin. In my pom.xml file I have

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.Release</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have several other services registering, so I know I have all my URL and settings correct. But I am not seeing is the registering log in the config server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after running the config server in debug mode.

```
   SpringBootAdminClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Spring Boot Client is disabled, because 'spring.boot.admin.client.url' is empty. (SpringBootAdminClientEnabledCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   SpringBootAdminClientCloudFoundryAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Spring Boot Client is disabled, because 'spring.boot.admin.client.url' is empty. (SpringBootAdminClientEnabledCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)
```

Since the config server doesn't read from the config server git repo the client URL was not set.

Adding `--spring.boot.admin.client.url=<url>` to the startup fixed it.